# rail: how to know which action in after_xxx in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in my model

```
after_create :publish_properties
after_update :publish_properties
before_destroy :publish_properties
```

Inside `publish_properties`, how can i know which was the action (`update, create or delete`) ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the callback block syntax (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-registration) to explicitly call your callback with the action type like this

```rb
after_create { publish_properties :create }
...

def publish_properties(action_type)
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `transaction_include_any_action`. You can do this by using the below code in your function to get the action name

**Rails 4+**

```
self.transaction_include_any_action?([:<action_name>])
```

**Rails < 4**

```
self.transaction_include_action?([:<action_name>])
```

In this action names can be :create, :destroy, :commit, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able [action_name](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/AbstractController/Base/action_name) to get the action name that the controller processed.